# How to resize a single element in a HTML page so that the rest fits the window without scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a few component on my page, one of them being a potentially long list of items. I want the scroll bar to be added for the table element, the page itself should never have a vertical scroll bar unless other components dictate this. The header and footer should always be fixed on the page head / foot (this should be already done in the example by using `height%` on the `body`.

[image]

My question is very similar to [this one about Responsive height layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50498123/responsive-height-layout-with-dynamic-height-elements). The major difference is my "results table" can be very long (tall) and I want it to scroll as necessary - it should be as high as possible, but the page should not have a scroll bar, only the results table.

Currently I use `50 vh` attribute on the element I want eventually to be shrunk, which prevents it from growing too large, but this is far from flexible or responsive.

```css
.whole {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
}

.header {
  flex: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc
}

.navigation {
  flex: 1;
  height: 50vh;
  overflow: auto
}

.article {
  flex: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 1px
}

.footer {
  flex: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #caa
}
```

```html
<div class="whole">
  <div class="header">
    Header
  </div>

  <div class="main">
    <div class="navigation">
      <ul>
        <li>Table</li>
        <li>of</li>
        <li>Contents</li>
        <li></li>
        <li>should be shrinked</li>
        <li>as necessary</li>
        <li></li>
        <li>with vertical scrollbar as needed</li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="article">

    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    Footer
  </div>
</div>
```

What CSS attributes (`max-height`, `height`, ...) can I use on my `.navigation` element so that the element shrinks as necessary to prevent the scrollbar appearing for the page?

I do not mind using Javascript including jQuery to achieve the layout. I do not care about old browsers (Internet Explorer) compatibility.

Comment: you can apply `overflow-y: hidden` to the whole and body.

Comment: @AneesIjaz I think that would hide the scrollbar, but the content would still be offscreen (and the footer most likely invisible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a CSS grid along with `overflow-y: auto;`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.whole {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto minmax(0, 1fr) auto;
  grid-template-areas: "header" "main" "footer";
}

.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(0, 1fr) 100px;
  grid-template-areas: "navigation" "article";
}

.header {
  background-color: #ccc;
  grid-area: header;
}

.navigation {
  grid-area: navigation;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.article {
  grid-area: article;
  height: 100px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: #caa;
}
```

```html
<div class="whole">
  <div class="header">
    Header
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="navigation">
      <ul>
        <li>Table</li>
        <li>of</li>
        <li>Contents</li>
        <li></li>
        <li>should be shrinked</li>
        <li>as necessary</li>
        <li></li>
        <li>with vertical scrollbar as needed</li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="article"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    Footer
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How is CSS grid related to flex layout? Can it be used with it, or is it something which is used instead of flex?

Comment: It is newer than flex, and in contrast to flex, able to create layouts based on columns **and** rows. You use either.